# How to invisible widget when there is no data in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am new to flutter, i'm trying to invisible button when there is no data in Firebase.

To get data i'm using `StreamBuilder`, if `snapshot.data!.docs` is `null` i want to invisible `CustomButton` which is outside of `StreamBuilder`.

**StreamBuilder:**

```
bool _isVisible = true; //variable

@override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: _appBar(context),
      body: CommonRefreshIndicator(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(_currentUser!.uid)
              .collection('favourites')
              .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const CustomProgressIndicator();
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CustomProgressIndicator();
            }

            final data = snapshot.data!.docs;
            allData = snapshot.data!.docs;

            if (data.isNotEmpty) {   //update based on data
              _isVisible = true;  
            } else {
              _isVisible = false;
            }

            return data.isNotEmpty
                ? _favItemListView(data)
                : const Center(
                    child: Text('No data found'),
                  );
          },
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _addAllToFavButton(size),
    );
  }
```

**CustomButton:**

```
Padding _addAllToFavButton(Size size) => Padding(
        padding: kSymmetricPaddingHor,
        child: Visibility(
          visible: _isVisible,
          child: CustomButton(
            label: 'Add all to my cart',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ),
      );
```

i have tried with `Visibility` widget and its work but whenever i'm deleting all data `CustomButton` is still visible, to invisivle `CustomButton` every time need to do hot reload.

**NOTE:** `setState` is also not working its giving me [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nLEm.jpg)

if any one can help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide your `CustomButton` when there is no data  you can try this:

Put your `_favItemListView(data) & _addAllToFavButton(size)` inside `Stack` and give `Positioned` to your `CustomButton` with its **bottom : 1** property.

**StreamBuilder**

```
return data.isNotEmpty
       ? Stack(
          children: [
           _favItemListView(data),
           _addAllToFavButton(size),
          ],
        )
        : const Center(
           child: Text('No data found'),
        );
```

**CustomButton:**

```
Positioned _addAllToFavButton(Size size) => Positioned(
        width: size.width,
        bottom: 1,                        //bottom property
        child: Padding(
          padding: kSymmetricPaddingHor,
          child: CustomButton(
            label: 'Add all to my cart',
            onPressed: () {}
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the snapshot has any data by using `snapshot.data!.data()!.isNotEmpty`

then

```
if(snapshot.data!.data()!.isNotEmpty){
               //show your data widget
// using a variable might require you to call a setstate but since 
//the widget is building here you might get some errors, its safe to just show your widget if data exists
             }else{
               ///no data here 
             }
```

Also to get the `.data()` you need to tell your stream that its a of type `<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` as `. .snapshots()` returns  `Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance..
```

Comment: `snapshot.data!.docs` is working perfectly, i want to change _isVisible to true when data.isNotEmpty and false when data.isEmpty.

Comment: ideally you should use setstate, but wont work during widget build

Comment: then what should i do to update _isVisible variable without hot reloading?

Comment: nope, render your widget

Comment: check comments in the code in the answer

Comment: it dose not work. still need to do hot reload to invisible